# Can Xamarin.Essentials track first launch even the user delete and re-download the application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.essentials

I am developing an application which will award user 200points when they first download the application, and I found that Xamarin.Essentials able to track whether the user is first time launching the application, but will it able to track even the user re-download the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I test it in my device, after uninstalling this application, then you re-intall it, it will show the first lauch. the best way to achieve it by registering accounts for users.After user registration, you can give 200points to this account.